# Prove that : $|P(\mathbb{R}) \setminus P(\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z})| = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Prove that: $|P(\mathbb{R}) \setminus P(\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z})| = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$

It is obvious that: $P(\mathbb{R}) \setminus P(\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z}) \subseteq P(\mathbb{R})$ so: $|P(\mathbb{R}) \setminus P(\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z})| \le  2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$

But I don't know how to prove that it is also $\ge 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.

Comment: Can you prove that the power set of $\mathbb R$ is equinumerous to the power set of $(0,1)$? Now add one or more integers to each element of the latter.

Comment: For $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $X \not\subseteq \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ iff $X \cap \mathbb{Z} \ne \emptyset$.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use $\aleph$ for the cardinality of the continuum. This notation is not common, and it easily leads to confusion (e.g. see the editors who changed it to $\aleph_0$ in your post). Better to use $2^{\aleph_0}$ or $\beth_1$ or $\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: Also, "It is obvious that Prove that :" makes no sense.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks for the correction. I meant that its easy to show the first side of the inequality, but the second part is hard and I can't find a way to solve it...

Comment: @Troposphere I am not sure that I understand. What do you mean by adding an integer? How is that connects to the required set?

Comment: @MathLover: For example if $A$ is any subset of $(0,1)$, then $A\cup\{42,137,1729\}$ is an element of $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)\setminus\mathcal P(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Z)$.